# Export array to excel xlsx in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, export-to-excel, xlsx

There is one requirement in javascript to export the data (array or array of objects) to excel xlsx. I already exported the data to csv but unable to do same for xlsx. I tried many api from github so that I can used the libraries and export it to xslx but there are little help for it. I tried using stephen-hardy/xlsx.js, SheetJS/js-xlsx etc.

For exporting to csv I used this Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side)! but the same cant be done for xlsx.

I tried xlsxwriter also to convert and write javascript array or array of object to xlsx but no result.

Now I m badly stuck because of the requirement. I also found out the similar post as of mine requirement Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264165/build-xlsx-file-with-javascript)!

Please guys give me solution if any

Answer (score 1):

A while ago, I wrote the following article, which described how to export data from a `jqGrid` to a "real" .xlsx file:

[Export jqGrid to Excel](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/784342/Export-Data-from-jqGrid-into-a-real-Excel-File)

This basically cached the jqGrid's data into a JavaScript variable, posted it back to a server, to save into Excel.   The Excel file is created using the OpenXML libraries.

This should point you in the right direction.

Alternatively, you might like to try this library:

[AlaSQL](https://github.com/agershun/alasql)

(I haven't tried this though.)

Answer (score 0):

Try excelbuilderjs, I have done the same of downloading a Json Object with array of items into an excel sheet using this library.If you can please share the code on Jsfiddle, i can take a look at it and help you out

http://excelbuilderjs.com/

Comment: var testdata = [
                   ["fruits","frozen","fresh","rotten"],
                   ["apples",884,494,494],
                   ["oranges",4848,494,4949],
                   ["kiwi",848,33,33]
               ]; //This is my javascript array I want to export it to xlsx